# Unicorn with Capistrano restart doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I have two Rails4-Apps set up on my server with Capistrano 2.15, Unicorn and Nginx.

When I do `cap:deploy`, I get this error:

```
executing "/etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp1 restart"
servers: ["123.45.678.910"]
[123.45.678.910] executing command
** [out :: 123.45.678.910] Couldn't reload, starting 'cd/home/deployer/apps/myapp1/current; bundle exec unicorn -D -c /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production' instead
** [out :: 123.45.678.910] 
** [out :: 123.45.678.910] master failed to start, check stderr log for details
command finished in 1845ms
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'ruby-2.0.0-p353' -c '/etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp1 restart'" on 123.45.678.910
```

**Further Information**:

- If I kill the workers manually on the server, the deployment process
  works (but the restart error still shows up).
- I **suspect**, the error has something to do with the fact, that I'm running 2 Apps simultaneously. If I'm running only one app it works.

**Output for `finalize_update` step:**

```
* 2014-01-13 13:31:11 executing `deploy:finalize_update'
    triggering before callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * 2014-01-13 13:31:11 executing `deploy:assets:symlink'
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/releases/20140113123110/public/assets && mkdir -p /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/releases/20140113123110/public && mkdir -p /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/shared/assets && ln -s /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/shared/assets /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/releases/20140113123110/public/assets"
    servers: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 816ms
  * 2014-01-13 13:31:12 executing `bundle:install'
  * executing "cd /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/releases/20140113123110 && bundle install --gemfile /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/releases/20140113123110/Gemfile --path /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
    servers: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 2048ms
  * executing "chmod -R -- g+w /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/releases/20140113123110 && rm -rf -- /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/releases/20140113123110/public/system && mkdir -p -- /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/releases/20140113123110/public/ && ln -s -- /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/shared/system /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/releases/20140113123110/public/system && rm -rf -- /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/releases/20140113123110/log && ln -s -- /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/shared/log /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/releases/20140113123110/log && rm -rf -- /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/releases/20140113123110/tmp/pids && mkdir -p -- /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/releases/20140113123110/tmp/ && ln -s -- /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/shared/pids /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/releases/20140113123110/tmp/pids"
    servers: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 512ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:finalize_update'
  * 2014-01-13 13:31:15 executing `deploy:symlink_config'
  * executing "ln -nfs /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/shared/config/database.yml /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/releases/20140113123110/config/database.yml"
    servers: ["xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"]
    [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] executing command
    command finished in 615ms
    triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
* 2014-01-13 13:31:15 executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
```

**Nginx.conf**:

```
upstream myapp.example.com {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.myapp.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name myapp.example.com;
  root /home/deployer/apps/myapp/current/public;

  location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
    root /home/deployer/apps/myapp/current/public;
    gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @myapp.example.com;
  location @myapp.example.com {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://myapp.example.com;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

The **Unicorn log** shows this error:

```
/home/deployer/apps/myapp1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:219:in `pid=': Already running on PID:20755 (or $
        from /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:142:in `start'
        from /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.7.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
        from /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

This is my **unicorn.rb** file:

```
root = "/home/deployer/apps/myapp1/current"
working_directory root
pid "#{root}/tmp/pids/unicorn-myapp1.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.myapp1.sock"
worker_processes 2
timeout 30

# Force the bundler gemfile environment variable to
# reference the capistrano "current" symlink
before_exec do |_|
  ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = File.join(root, 'Gemfile')
end
```

**Capfile**:

```
load 'deploy'
load 'deploy/assets'
load 'config/deploy'
```

This is my **unicorn_init.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Manage unicorn server
# Description:       Start, stop, restart unicorn server for a specific application.
### END INIT INFO
set -e

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/home/deployer/apps/myapp1/current
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
AS_USER=deployer
set -u

OLD_PIN="$PID.oldbin"

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PIN && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PIN`
}

run () {
  if [ "$(id -un)" = "$AS_USER" ]; then
    eval $1
  else
    su -c "$1" - $AS_USER
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
  sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
stop)
  sig QUIT && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
force-stop)
  sig TERM && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
restart|reload)
  sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
upgrade)
  if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
  then
    n=$TIMEOUT
    while test -s $OLD_PIN && test $n -ge 0
    do
      printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
    done
    echo

    if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $OLD_PIN
    then
      echo >&2 "$OLD_PIN still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
      exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
  fi
  echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
reopen-logs)
  sig USR1
  ;;
*)
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

And here is my **deploy.rb**:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
require "rvm/capistrano"

set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-2.0.0-p353'
set :rvm_type, :user

server "123.456.789.101", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "myapp1"
set :user, "deployer"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:myusername/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"


default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

before "deploy:restart", :symlink_directories
task :symlink_directories do
  run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/uploads #{release_path}/public/uploads"
end

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end

  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

Comment: `master failed to start, check stderr log for details`
Did you check your log file for errors?

Comment: @ErezRabih it says, that PID is already running. I added the complete error to my question.

Answer (score 10):

You probably have a permission problem:

During deployment, capistrano tries to restart unicorn as using the init script. The init script tries to send the HUP signal to the master to signal it to restart its workers. If this fails, the script assumes that unicorn is not running and tries to start a new instance. When this happens, you get the error that you are experiencing (when the new instance tries to start, it notices the already running instance and terminates with the error you get).

So sending the HUP signal to the unicorn master seems to be failing in your case. I suspect this is due to a permission problem. Please check that unicorn is started by the same user that you are using during deploying (your config looks correct, using *deployer* everywhere, but maybe the unicorn process that is currently running was started by root or someone else?).

For troubleshooting, I suggest the following:

1. log into your server and check that unicorn was started by *deployer* (using `ps` or `top`)
2. verify that the pidfile exists in `APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid` and contains the current pid of the unicorn master
3. become *deployer* and try to send the HUP signal to unicorn (`sudo su deployer` and then `kill -HUP PID_OF_UNICORN_MASTER`)
4. if this works, try `/etc/init.d/unicorn_xxx restart` as *deployer*
5. if this works but deploys with capistrano still won't work, please report back ;)

#### Update:

I quickly scanned your deploy.rb again and found something that might not be correct: please make sure that the directory `APP_ROOT/tmp/pids` is shared between all releases. Otherwise, unicorn writes its pidfile into this subdir in one release, and when you deploy a new release, unicorn can't find the pidfile since it is in a subdir in the old release...
If you are using capistrano version 3, you can achieve this by including a line like

```
set :linked_dirs, [... 'tmp/pids' ...]
```

in your deploy.rb...

#### Another update (tl;dr):

To properly restart during a deploy, unicorn needs a valid pidfile at the location specified in the config file. In addition, the user as which unicorn is run needs proper permissions to write to this pidfile.

It has become standard for Rails apps to store pidfiles in the `APP_ROOT/tmp/pids` directory.

Since capistrano creates a new (app) directory for each deploy, it needs some trickery to keep shared data accessible from all releases/deploys. It does so by linking a couple of directories (including `tmp/pids`) to directories in a shared location.

If all this is happening correctly, then restarting unicorn will work correctly.

*(I will update this answer as soon as the problem is completely resolved. Please also read the discussion in the comments to this answer...)*

Comment: 1: I double-checked that unicorn was started by _deployer_. 2: `kill -HUP PID_OF_UNICORN_MASTER`killed the two workers and the master is still in the list when `ps aux | grep unicorn`. 3. when restarting unicorn as deployer, I get the same error... 4. `cap:deploy` same error

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. The exact commando that the init script executes for signalling HUP is `test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 \`cat $PID\``. So could you also please test whether `test -s /home/deployer/apps/myapp1/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid && echo 'good' || echo 'bad'` prints out *good*?

Comment: I updated my answer slightly, please read through it again and report back!

Comment: Thanks for your help. `test -s ...` echos **bad**... How do I set the linked_dirs in Capistrano 2?

Comment: The default capistrano 2 setup should take care of this during the `finalize_update` step (configured using the `shared_children` variable). Could you check your output regarding the `finalize_update` step and maybe post it in your question?

Comment: Judging from that output the pid directory should be linked correctly. .. Could you please do the following: 1. Kill the unicorn master process. 2. Make sure that there is no pidfile in `APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/` (delete it if necessary). 3. Start unicorn. 4. Verify that a pidfile is written and contains the pid of the unicorn master process...

Comment: I did all of your steps and they worked. After starting unicorn again, the pidfile is written and contains the pid of the unicorn master. I recognized one thing: If I do manual `restart` I get the same error as in `cap:deploy`, but if I just do a manual 'start' there is no error. Could I just exclude `restart` from my deploy.rb and use start instead?

Comment: Well, normally you have unicorn running when deploying, so you want to `restart` it. Just `start`ing it will not work if unicorn is already running. Also, capistrano will be executing the task `deploy:restart` during deploys, so it needs to be there...

Comment: Ok, I get it. So my problem has nothing to do with Capistrano, because I can't even restart unicorn manually from the server. Could the workers from my second app be the reason for that?

Comment: Another go at troubleshooting: 1. Make sure that you have unicorn running in a consistent state (started as *deployer*, the pidfile existing at `/home/deployer/apps/myapp1/shared/pids/unicorn.pid`, writable by *deployer* and containing the correct pid). 2. Change your `deploy:restart` task to do nothing (comment out the line `run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"`). 3. Do a deploy using capistrano. 4. Verify that `/home/deployer/apps/myapp1/current/tmp/pids` is linked to the shared directory and that the unicorn pidfile still contains the correct pid. continued in next comment...

Comment: continued from previous comment: If the pidfile is set up correct, then you definitely have a problem with just unicorn and your capistrano setup is working correctly...

Comment: Did all of your suggestions and the pidfile is set up correctly. So it's about unicorn. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45213/discussion-between-severin-and-kentucky)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried running `sudo update-rc.d unicorn_myapp1 defaults` while you are SSHed in to your server?  This has taken care of the error for me in the past.

============ UPDATE ============

I've included a deploy.rb file I use that has never given me any issues.  See if it works for you, obviously make some edits.  I'm super busy right now, so I don't have the time to compare it against your existing deploy.rb file, but maybe this will offer some guidance --

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
# YOU WILL NEED TO ADD THE LINE FOR RVM HERE

server "162.xxx.xxx.xxx", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "APPLICATION-NAME"
set :user, "deployer"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:GITHUB-USER-NAME/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.example.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

Comment: Nope, nothing changed. This is the output I get after your command: `System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp1 already exist.`

Comment: what's your Cap File look like?

Comment: added capfile to question

Comment: and one last piece to the puzzle, possibly is - your deploy.rb file.  Need to see all of the moving parts to get a full grasp of what is actually going on.

Comment: I included my deploy.rb to my question.

Comment: @KenTucky - I'm assuming your deploy file has been edited to protect some personal information? Other wise I see what might be the problem.

Comment: yeah sure ;-) I edited IP and names for security reasons

Comment: @KenTucky - check my updated answer and see if that helps.  Sorry for not adding more detail.  Slammed with work today.

Comment: it's basically the same deploy.rb except for the symlink_directories task to prevent deletion of files in /uploads

Answer (score 0):

Based on your restart command

```
sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
run "$CMD" # this is just running start
```

The HUP signal is exiting with an error as evidenced by "Couldn't reload" message in your Cap error, which then will go to the next line running the start command, which is running, as your error log is telling you. (FWIW always trust your logging as a start point)

You'll have to diagnose why HUP isn't working. You may have to switch to sending signals in this order USR2 --> WINCH --> QUIT and utilizing their exit states to get it working. :-/

FWIW this was my [control script](https://gist.github.com/nacengineer/4561850) when I was using Unicorn... although it did at random times fail during the restart. But the messaging is more verbose and should help.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is very simple: You already have a server running and its PID is 20755.
You need to kill it first with `sudo kill 20755`
And then try to re-run the unicorn command.

Comment: I'm already doing this (it's written in my question). I'd like to kill them automatically when I do `cap:deploy`